# Login Problem after home folder name changed

Tags: users, home-directory

I have changed my home folder name through command `mv olderFolder newFolder` and then restarted, but not able to login. What step did I miss?

Comment: Normally, one does not rename the home folder. Why did you do it, in the first place? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

After rename your home directory you should still tell linux about your new home directory
This can be done by editing /etc/passwd file

Just open that file and change /home/olderFolder to /home/newFolder

**For Example:**

**OLD:**

```
mitesh:x:1000:1000:Mitesh Shah:/home/mitesh:/bin/bash
```

**NEW:**

```
mitesh:x:1000:1000:Mitesh Shah:/home/miteshshah:/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea (as you found out) to rename your home folder.

If you can, log in as root and rename your folder by issuing

```
sudo mv /home/newFolder /home/olderFolder
```

If you don't have a root login, get an Live CD, boot it, don't install but simply 'repair' an existing installation. Mount the drive and rename the home folder similar to what is shown above.